# pip3 --version directory is different than "which pip3"

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip

how do i make the `which pip3` the same directory as `pip3 --version`?

I have a mac. os sierra. python3.6. i'm having issues with `pip3`. i would like to continue working in python3.6 without using homebrew or virtual environment.

pip3:

```
$ which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3

$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

pip:

```
$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip

$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: These are the same. 9.0.1 only means the version number of *pip*. The `which` shows the version of *Python* for which it maintains packages.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, OP is trying to figure out why `which` and `--version` point to the same directory for `pip` but point to different directories for `pip3`.  I don't think he's actually worried about the 9.0.1 part.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt: well in that case, because the packages are not stored where the binary is stored. And the title says "version is different".

Comment: thanks for your quick replies. how do i put the pip3 packages in the same place?

Comment: i made changes to the question to clarify. thanks for the edits @WillemVanOnsem. this is my first question and while the format might not have been proper, i think the substance of the question is. any clarification why this was downvoted would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can not make the "which pip3" and "pip3 --version" the same. It is not even supposed to point out to the same thing because "which pip" points to the location of binary which gets executed when you type pip3. However, when you do a "pip3 --version", it tells you the location where the pip is installed. All the other python libraries are also at the same location.

Comment: can you elaborate how  pip3 version would point to the same location of the binary in which it gets executed?

Comment: which command basically searches the location of the executables which you set in the $PATH ... if you do an "echo $PATH" you can see the different paths set on your machine.
"--version" on the other hand is never meant to tell you that. It is just meant to give you the version of the software and tell where the files of that particular installation reside. So if you go to the path which "pip --version" shows, you can see all the libraries that you installed using pip whereas in the "which" command location you will only find the executables

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles upon this thread in search of a solution for the mismatch in pip (parent) path output by the commands in OP, when using conda environment e.g. for conda environment env

```
(env) $ pip --version
  pip 21.3.1 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(env) $ which pip 
  /home/user/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/pip
```

The following command from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069308/19941398) solves it:

```
(env) $ python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```