# Pip is selecting wrong path

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm using windows 10 and I got rid of python 3.8 and installed 3.7 as the only python version on my system.

When trying to install libraries using pip I now get the error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pygame_menu': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

when I checked in the console `which -a pip` I got:

```
C:\Users\User>which -a pip
/cygdrive/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Scripts/pip
/cygdrive/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/pip
```

Now when I look for Python in my variable path it is alright...
Anyways I can't figure out how to change the path of pip so the right one is selected... besides its pretty weird that ive uninstalled python and pip multiple times and it still gets it wrong every time during installation.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `python -m pip` for installing? And maybe editing your system path? Also, if your path is already set correctly, make sure you restart your command prompt too

Comment: Have you Tried `python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`

Comment: You can remove one of the pip path from the environment variables

Comment: Having Same Problem I am Referring to [#63396570](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64734712/python-cant-use-pip-after-uninstall-3-9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to fix do this :

1. check if you still have the python38-32 folder in your local variable list
2. Delete the "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38"   folder
3. run pip from command line

if the problem still persists then type "environment variables" in the windows search box

and add  "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37" to your system variable named "Path"

This should completely fix your problem

if not

1. uninstall all the python files including py launcher
2. reinstall python # when installing you must select `ADD PYTHON to system environment variable`

Comment: I had to delete *all* the folders for *all older versions* of python to get this working...  so step 2 repeatedly for each folder.

Answer (score 13):

For me this solution did the job, thanks itsAPK

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

The cause of this problem was me installing python from Microsoft store and having another version installed from the default installer, when I removed the Microsoft store version it was prompting me with errors.

Comment: This helped me with a similar but different problem -- pip was trying to run python from the wrong path -- as in, a different user name, due to how I migrated from another computer.  But this still solved my problem beautifully!

Comment: Helped me as well. Though make sure to run following commands in a new terminal, so dependency changes will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

When I was facing the same issue I fixed it by checking the python version pointed to by `pip3.x` executable. The pip3.10 was pointing to `/usr/bin/python9` which was causing problems with package installation.
Just check if your `pip3.x` is pointing to the correct python version.

`vim $HOME/.local/bin/pip3.10`

Python version is on the first line (starting with the '#').