# Python Can't Use Pip After Uninstall 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, pip

### Problem

I Uninstalled Python 3.9 as I tried to import matplotlib
and would not work. After looking around for solutions I found out matplotlib may not be supported with 3.9 OK no problem. I'll uninstall 3.9 and install 3.7 Once done I tried to pip install matplotlib and the problem underlined in green **(In photo)**. Happens I've change the environment variables as shown **(In photo)** and when I go into the file only 3.7 is there. Not sure why it's doing this maybe someone ran into the same issues as I but it was working fine until I uninstalled 3.9 I will keep it updated until CMD problem is sloved.

### Solutions I Tried

- Uninstalled and Reinstalled *(From installer itself)*
- Remove environment variables and add environment variables again
- Restarted Terminal and Computer
- Repair Installation
- where pip **OUTPUT:** `"C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\pip.exe C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe)"`
- Change Environment Variable name from *Python* to Path

### Update

I downloaded anaconda and using the powershell prompt and it seems to work now, but with the default CMD it does not work.

### Solution Fixed for CMD

Found out pycharm projects did not remove the script files from 3.9 and had to go in manually and remove it `C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts` once any 3.9 scripts where removed I was then able to use pip as normal. Recommend either uninstall Pycharm or *(IDE)* and reinstall with correct interrupter I'f you're switching from 3.9 to lower.

### Photo's

Here was the: [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXoAt.jpg) **with CMD**
Here's the: [Solution Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJCYo.jpg) **with anaconda**
Here's the: [Solution Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXMOr.png) **with CMD**

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. In the future, please embed any images you share as part of your answer or question directly in your post instead of as links to external sites. Leaving links to external sites will accelerate bit rot here.

Comment: You're welcome quite happy it works took me couple hours of head scratched haha, My apologies I'm fairly new and trying to figure the nooks and flow of it all.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing `python -m pip install package`

If you are in Linux, execute `whereis python` and then add a version to the PATH, then you can execute the `pip` as well.
Other way is to install a new version. PIP only works with a version of python installed

Comment: I've tired that and still does not work. I cant use pip for anything as it seems to be reading a PATH that's not there. Instead of the new path When i run that command nothing happens and executes a blank command

Comment: Maybe you need to update the PATH for the new python installation

Comment: Yeah, For some reason my pycharm was reading the 3.9 pip that was in my projects and not the 3.7 pip i had doubles in the project for some odd reason so i had to go in manually and remove the 3.9 pip and it worked afterwords. I've updated my solutions above.