# Python installation getting pip Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip

I am using Windows 11. I uninstalled python 3.9 and installed python 3.12 (Windows installer (64-bit)). I checked the box add python.exe to path. As part the procedures' I was able to change the environmental variable of "path" to include

- C:\Users...\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\
- C:\Users...\Programs\Python\Python312\

I have another variable "pip" with value of

- C:\Users...\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe

**in command prompt**

I enter > `python --version` I get `Python 3.12.1` in response.

I entered `py get-pip.py` and I get the message `Successfully installed pip-23.3.1`

I enter > `pip freeze` and I get

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users...\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users...\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" freeze': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I already changed environmental variable, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Command Prompt type in

> $ which -a pip

If the files were not changed then the response should be two file locations:

> /c/Users/.../Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/pip
> /c/Users/.../Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/pip

Rename or remove the folder `Python39`
This will this will force pip to use the new folder location.

for additional details / solutions [Pip shows wrong path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63396749/5091720)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your system is still trying to use the pip executable from the Python 3.9 directory, which no longer exists. Here are a few steps you can try to resolve this issue:
Check your Environment Variables: Make sure that the paths to Python 3.12 and its Scripts directory are correctly set in your PATH environment variable1. Remove any references to Python 3.9.
Reinstall pip for Python 3.12: You can try reinstalling pip specifically for Python 3.12 by running the following command in your command prompt:
$python -m pip install --upgrade pip

This command uses Python 3.12 (since python --version gives you Python 3.12.1) to upgrade pip2.
Use pip via python -m: If the above steps don’t work, as a workaround, you can use pip via the -m option with python. Instead of using pip freeze, use:

$python -m pip freeze

This should bypass the launcher and use the pip associated with your Python 3.12 installation1.
Remember to replace python with the full path to your Python 3.12 executable if python --version doesn’t give you Python 3.12.1.
If none of these steps work, there might be an issue with your Python installation. In that case, you might want to consider uninstalling Python 3.12 and reinstalling it1. Make sure to check the box that says “Add Python to PATH” during the installation process.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a problem with your system trying to use an outdated version of a tool called "`pip`" that's associated with an older version of Python (Python 3.9). Here are some simple steps you can try to fix this:

1. Check Your Computer Settings:
   Make sure your computer knows where to find the new version of Python (Python 3.12). It's like making sure your computer knows where to look for things.
2. Update `pip` for the New Python:
   Try updating the tool "`pip`" so that it works with the new Python version (Python 3.12). You can do this by running a command in a special window. Don't worry about the technical details; just follow the command: $`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.
3. Use a Different Way to Run `pip`:
   If the above step doesn't work, there's another way to use "`pip`". Instead of a direct command, you can use a longer one: $`python -m pip freeze`. Again, this is just a workaround, a different way to get things done.
4. If Nothing Works, Try Reinstalling Python:
   If none of these steps fix the issue, it might be best to uninstall the new Python (Python 3.12) and install it again. When you do this, make sure to check a box that says something like "*Add Python to PATH*" during the installation. It's a simple setting that can help your computer find Python easily.